# Yarn UI not accessible. Accessing YARN UI on 8088 port says server not found

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn, hadoop2

Here is my yarn-site.xml file :

```
<property>
<name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services</name>
<value>mapreduce_shuffle</value>
</property>

<property>
<name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services.mapreduce.shuffle.class</name>
<value>org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ShuffleHandler</value>
</property>

<property>
<name>yarn.resourcemanager.resource-tracker.address</name>
<value>master:8031</value>
</property>

<property>
<name>yarn.resourcemanager.scheduler.address</name>
<value>master:8030</value>
</property>
<property>

<name>yarn.resourcemanager.address</name>
<value>master:8032</value>
</property>

<property>
<name>yarn.log-aggregation-enable</name>
<value>true</value>
</property>

<property>
<name>yarn.nodemanager.log-aggregation.roll-monitoring-interval-seconds</name>
<value>3600</value>
</property>


<property>
<name>yarn.nodemanager.vmem-pmem-ratio</name>
<value>16</value>
</property>

<property>
<name>yarn.nodemanager.pmem-check-enabled</name>
<value>true</value>
</property>

<property>
<name>yarn.nodemanager.vmem-check-enabled</name>
<value>false</value>
</property>

<property>
<name>yarn.nodemanager.resource.memory-mb</name>
<value>24576</value>
</property>

<property>
<name>yarn.scheduler.minimum-allocation-mb</name>
<value>2048</value>
</property>

</configuration>
```

When I am trying to access the YARN UI to monitor my jobs via the URL http://secondary:8088/proxy/application_xxxxxxxxxxxxx_xxxx/ by replacing the `secondary` with IP Address of the host in which namenode is running, I am getting `Server Not Found` error in Firefox. What configurations am I missing from the xml file to view my jobs via the UI ? I am using hadoop 2.5.2 It is 6 node cluster with 5 slaves and 1 master.

Here is my /etc/hosts file :

```
127.0.0.1 localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4 
::1 localhost localhost.localdomain localhost6 localhost6.localdomain6
10.0.70.149 secondary 
10.0.70.148 master 
10.0.70.143 slave1 
10.0.70.144 slave2 
10.0.70.145 slave3 
10.0.70.146 slave4 
10.0.70.147 slave5
```

Comment: `secondary` doesn't seems like a valid host name to me? are you sure that shouldn't be `localhost` or something like that? (I may be wrong, I don't know Hadoop/YARN)

Comment: Here is my /etc/hosts file to map IP to Hostname: `cat /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1   localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4
::1         localhost localhost.localdomain localhost6 localhost6.localdomain6

10.0.70.149 secondary
10.0.70.148 master
10.0.70.143 slave1
10.0.70.144 slave2
10.0.70.145 slave3
10.0.70.146 slave4
10.0.70.147 slave5`

Comment: Just curious, why are you using such an old version of Hadoop? And can you show the ResourceManager is actually running on that machine you're trying to reach? And you can 'ping secondary` from the machine you want to reach it from? In other words, this isn't a Hadoop problem, it's all general network stuff

Comment: @cricket_007 I inherited this setup from someone. I had some deadlines to met so I fixed the same hadoop version which was pre-installed rather than install a new one and create a multinode cluster from scratch. I am able to telnet the namenode server on the port on which yarn is running but somehow the UI is still not accessible. Thank you for all your help sir, I really appreciate it.

Comment: Are you able to access any UI? The Namenode or Datanode UI, for example? Can you show the output of `jps` command on the secondary server?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have errors in log, I solved the problem using 0.0.0.0 as yarn.resourcemanager.hostname in yarn-site.xml

See all paroperties
https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-common/yarn-default.xml